# How does pyaramorph (Arabic morphological analyzer) work?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, arabic

I have downloaded pyaramorph (Arabic morphological analyzer) on python , but I do not know how to use it. Could someone explain to me how can I get it to work?

If I have articles and I want to use this morphological tools to know how many (root) words I found it?

Comment: How about you give a try to find something yourself? First result from google http://home.uchicago.edu/~alexlee/pyaramorph/

Comment: I know about this website but I don't know how does it work?

Comment: What doesn't work? They provide example how to use it.

Comment: I tried to use this example and the output as following                                                        >>> loading dictPrefixes ... loaded 299 entries
loading dictStems ... loaded 38600 lemmas and 82158 entries
loading dictSuffixes ... loaded 618 entries
Unicode Arabic Morphological Analyzer (press ctrl-d to exit)
$  كتب كتابا في المكتب
Decode error. Skipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file pyaramorph.py, in editor change line 262 from:

```
s = raw_input("$ ")
```

to:

```
s = raw_input("$ ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))
```

Or better follow what authors say [here](http://home.uchicago.edu/~alexlee/pyaramorph/#requirements).